# mqtt know when queue is processed?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Is there any way for a mqtt client to know when his queue was processed and he is "up-to-date" again?

I want to prevent editing of certain elements in the frontend until I am sure that I received all queued changes after a reconnect.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, queued messages are not flagged in any way, but they will all be delivered as soon as the client connects.

You could just set a flag when connecting to just stop all UI updates for a period of time to allow messages to arrive and then update with the last data.